# Verifying file integrity with Python

Tags: python, gzip, pickle

I have a directory with many big files. They have all been created with this line of code:

```
pickle.dump(variable, gzip.open(file_name, 'wb'), -1)
```

So they are basically compressed, serialized variables.

Now, at some point, a crash/interruption (or several) might have occurred in the past while executing that exact line. However I just do not know if that happened.

So, first, I am assuming that if something unexpected happened, there is the possibility of having a `file_name` in the file system which is corrupted, and does not (at least fully) contain the compressed, serialized `variable`. Am I right here?

Now I wonder if there is a way to check the integrity of those files without having to load them to memory one by one. I am trying to avoid executing `pickle.load(gzip.open(file_name, 'rb'))` with `try/except`.

Is this possible? Is there another (faster) way to check if `pickle` and `gzip` both finished successfully?

Comment: Presumably, next time you will make the pickle process create an extra flag file for each pickle file, once the pickle is complete. Not that that helps.

Comment: @barny: Heh, that would have been awesome, yeah. ^^

Comment: Can you check the files modified dates - most recent are likely to be the dodgy ones

Comment: @barry: I can check those dates, but that would not help. I did not generate those files, so I do not have information about when a crash/interruption occurred (if any!). All I know is it might have happened zero or more times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I do not think that it is possible to check the validity of a gzip file other than by decompressing it, the pickled data protocol contains a `STOP` opcode that should be present at the end of all pickled data. (If it is missing, unpickling will raise an `EOFError`). This stop opcode is the `.` character. Thus you could partially check the validity of a pickle by checking if it ends with the `.` character. This also means that you can concatenate two valid pickles, and then unpickling the result twice will get the two objects. All pickles in protocol two or higher also begin with a `\x80` (`€`) character.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me speeding up the verification process a lot. I posted an answer with the code I am using, just for reference...

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [@ppperry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33938986/3577054), I found a solution which is faster than de-serializing everything into memory.

```
f = gzip.open(file_name, 'rb')
f.seek(-1, os.SEEK_END)
f.read(1) == bytes('.', 'utf8')
```

Note that:

- The second line can crash if the compressed file is malformed (use `try/except`).
- The third line is the one which reads the last byte, which should be `.`.

Comment: Although the `seek` part is still slow (with `gzip`, you need to decompress the full stream), it is much faster, as you don't need to load everything into RAM. Therefore, it is easy to spawn multiple processes to execute this task in parallel without worrying about memory consumption (only CPU workload). Faster and memory-efficient solution. Of course verifying the last byte in the pickle stream is not 100% effective, but for most cases it should do (it's all a trade-off between speed and accuracy/reliability).

Comment: Especially since data corruption is more likely to affect the end of the data stream that the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following method in python 2.6. 
In Python 2.7 you can use **with as**

```
try:                             
    f = gzip.open(filepath, 'rb')
    f._read_gzip_header()        
    return True                  
except Exception, e:             
    print e                      
    return False                 
finally:                         
    f.close()
```